# Youtube embedded player works <no wrap> but not onload

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have a player with a for loop counter underneath.

When I set the window to `onload`, the for loop works, but the youtube video does not display.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajLg0wf9/

When I set the window to `no wrap - bottom of <head>`, the youtube player works but the for loop doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/b8rha571/1/

What's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place youtube api functions at global level not inside onLoad event, something like this:

```
<script>
 var player;
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'wQxmK1CZwik',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
 }
 function onPlayerReady(event) {
    loopStart();
    player.playVideo();
 }
 function loopStart() {
    player.seekTo(7);   // Start at 7 seconds
 }
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        setTimeout(loopStart, 30000); // After 5 seconds, restart the loop
    }
 }

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var button = document.getElementById("clickme"),
  count = 0;
  button.onclick = function() {
     count += 1;
     button.innerHTML = "Click me: " + count;
  };
 });
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to do it correctly in jsfiddle but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/ajLg0wf9/10/